# Fancy background movement with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I want to make something similar to the CSS/JQUERY effect that you can see in the following error link:

```
http://new.livestream.com/error
```

What I want to know is how I can make the background image move according to the mouse position and using JQUERY. I have seen some code that could help me but since I'm not very keen on JQUERY I ask for some help.
I post the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#home a')
   // On mouse over, move the background on hover
   .mouseover(function(){
     $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: "0 -54px"}, 500);
   })
   // On mouse out, move the background back
   .mouseout(function(){
      $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: "0 0"}, 500);
   })
 });
```

I guess that I must change the values static "0 -54px" values to a dynamic values according the current mouse position right?

Best regards

Comment: There's plenty of JavaScript parallax scrolling scripts (and jQuery plugins) for this already, why not use one of them?

Comment: @TazeT.Schnitzel : because learning how to do things yourself (unless they get really complicated) is never a bad idea ;)

Comment: I know, I do that all the time :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, you'll probably want to listen for the `mouseMove()` event though

[See this link for the jQuery documentation on mouseMove](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/)

```
$("#target").mousemove(function(event) {
    var mouseX = event.pageX;
    var mouseY = event.pageY;
    // you can now use mouseX and mouseY to calculate and set the background position or offset
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have time to get the code working but for the people how wants the effect I was talking  about can use this tutorial :)

http://webdev.stephband.info/parallax.html

Best regards and may the force be with you!